# How to implement create and update in one API view.?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called **CarDetailsAdd** and **VehicleDetails** (field - description), VehicleDetails is a **Foreignkey** to **CarDetailsAdd**. I am using Nested Relationship in this serializer. Using this update function, I can update existing vehicle details. Add and update runs on the same screen, depending on the UI. If the user has updated the field, it should be updated or user has added a new field, it should be added. How do I do that if the user updates and adds at the same time.?

[image: (UI image)]

```
# Serializer

class CarDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vehicle_details = VehicleDetailsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CarDetailsAdd
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'year', 'color', 'fuel_type',
            'vehicle_details',
        )
        read_only_fields = ['id']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        vehicle_data = validated_data.pop('vehicle_details')

        vehicle = (instance.vehicle_details).all()

        vehicle = list(vehicle)

        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.year = validated_data.get('year', instance.year)
        instance.color = validated_data.get('color', instance.color)
        instance.fuel_type = validated_data.get('fuel_type', instance.fuel_type)
        instance.save()

        for vehicle_data in vehicle_data:
            vehicle = vehicle.pop(0)
            vehicle.description = vehicle_data.get('description', vehicle.description)
            vehicle.save()

        return instance
```

```
# View

class CarDetailsView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            car = self.get_object(pk)
            serializer = CarDetailsSerializer(car, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'response': 'Update Success', 'result': serializer.data})
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            return Response({'response': 'Oops! Something Went Wrong'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: If the vehicle has a primary key, then it is being updated.  If it doesn't, it is being added.

Comment: Also, take a look at this package.  You don't have to roll your own nested-model serializers: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Comment: **If the vehicle has a primary key, then it is being updated. If it doesn't, it is being added.** this is i want

Comment: @RossRogers: I got what I really needed from that package. **Thank you**

Comment: @RossRogers : When I use Base64ImageField to save images. The update function does not work properly in this drf-writeable-nested. This will replace the old image with the new one. But I also need the old image. what should I do .? Can you help me.?

Comment: Try out https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/